# Laravel - Sort collection with a specific order given by an array of ids

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I'm trying to achieve the following:

Lets say I have a collection of products like this one:

```
$products = [{ id: 1, name: example1, price: 10 }, {id: 2, name: example2, price: 20}]
```

And one array with one id:

```
[0 => 2]
```

I want to sort the $products collection with the array, that would result in showing the product with the id 2 first inside the collection or in similar words give order priority for the items in the collection which id is on the array, I hope you can understand me.

What I tried with no success (can't see any changes):

```
$events = $events->sortBy(function($model) use ($ToposDestaques) {
    return array_search($model->getKey(), $ToposDestaques);
});
```

$events has two items with id 1 and id 2.

$TopoDestaques has the following value:

```
array:1 [
  0 => 2
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should do that with `sortBy` function cause you sorting by the ID's array so you should iterate over it and not the collection.
This can be handled with PHP std only:

```
$products = [[ "id"=> 1, "name"=> "example1", "price"=> 10 ], [ "id"=> 2, "name"=> "example2", "price"=> 20 ],  [ "id"=> 3, "name"=> "example3", "price"=> 30 ]];
$sortByArr = [3, 2];

$sortedArray = array_reduce($sortByArr, function($array, $index) use (&$products) {
    $productIndex = array_search($index, array_column($products, "id"));
    $array[] = $products[$productIndex];
    unset($products[$productIndex]);
    return $array;
}, []);

var_dump(array_merge($sortedArray, $products));
```

Comment: It doesnt work, it results in a single item array and i dont want that, i want the same collection but reordered by the array of the ids.

Comment: I didn't write it because you can do it in several ways, and you need to choose the one who will cost you at least. I edited my answer to present one way to do this.